# Unable to import pygal in Python despite installing it

Tags: pygal

I have successfully installed pygal but I am not able to import it in Python. Can you please settle this issue? Has it anything to do with virtual environment? How do I install pygal in virtual environment.

Comment: With which command have you installed it? What is the output? With which command are yoj trying to import it? What is the output?

Comment: Can you ansewr one question please? Does Python 3.11.7 support pygal?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you created the virtual environment, how you installed pygal, what `which python` shows inside and outside your virtual environment, what version of python is running when you run your python code, etc, etc.

Comment: I don't know how to create a virtual environment. I just typed                              
python -m pip install --user pygal                                                                                           and installation was successful but I am not able to import pygal into Python. When I type                                                                                                                                   import pygal                                                                                                                       No module of thisname exists.

Comment: I just typed python -m pip install --user pygal and installed pygal successfully but when I import it in python using import pygal , it says module pygal does not exist. I never created any virtual environment.

Comment: @Baziga: It should work both inside and outside of a virtual environment (venv). So if you haven't created a virtual environment yet, you don't have to do it just to solve this problem. If you are already working with virtual environments, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are multiple Python versions installed or multiple virtual environments on your system, and you have installed the package to the wrong one.

Use the same `python` command to install and run (without the leading `$`):

```
$ python -m pip install pygal
...
$ echo "import pygal; echo OK" >myprog.py
$ python myprog.py
OK
```

If you use IDLE, then start it like this:

```
$ python -c "from idlelib.pyshell import main; main()"
```

(It's too late to change the Python version or the virtual environment after IDLE has been started. It's too late to select the Python version or the virtual environment after *pip install* has been started. You have to do it first, and then only run the `python` command.)

It's important that you start everything with the (same) `python` command (rather than `pip`, `idle` etc.), and from the same virtual environment (venv), if any. That's the way you can make sure that you will be using the same Python version and modules.

Comment: When I type python-m pip install pygal, it runs the message: "No module named install". Earlier it had run this install message.

Comment: That's a very unusual error message in thus situation, do you have a screenshot? Are you sure you have typed the command correctly?

Comment: Sir, can you please answer one question? When I run the python --version command in my virtual environment, it says Python 3.11.7. Whereas IDLE reveals the python version as 3.11.5. Can this be the reason why I am not able to import Pygal?

Comment: @Baziga: Yes, this is most likely the reason. I've extended my answer on how to have the same Python version in `python`, `pip` and `idle`.